# Loading svg image using xlink (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, iframe, svg, href, xlink

Can anyone help me figure out why the first image does not load in Chrome? Tested in Firefox and Safari, both are fine.

I create 2 iframes, one loading a dynamically generated svg image containing a protocol agnostic url:

`img1.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', url);`

Second one uses an absolute url.

`img2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http:'+url);`

Why doesn't Chrome want to load the first image?

Demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ioowilly/QbA2T/

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in Chrome. You should consider reporting it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code according its working in chrome

```
img1.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http:'+url);
```

Comment: I did that in the demo for the second image as an example. But why doesn't work without http?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QbA2T/1/

```
img1.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http:'+url);
```

You left out the 'http' + url from the first image.

Edit:

The problem is that without the http it can not evaluate the string, the last value is a string:

```
 value is the desired string value of the new attribute.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttributeNS

It will get added to your element but without any effect.

Comment: The question was why is http:// necessary in Chrome when in all other browsers // is enough. Also, the url is definitely a string. Thanks for the try though.